# SQL Selecting multiple columns based on max value in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

OK so I have looked theough the other solutions an no help. So here is what I am trying to do.
I need to select the row with multiple columns where the value in one column is the max value.

here is sample data

```
    orderfileid item number item cost   warehouse
    1           1234        3.45             ATL
    1           2345        1.67             DFW
    3           2345        2.45             NYY
    3           678         2.4              ORD
    2           1234        1.67             DFW
```

I need to select the entire row where the orderfileid is the max for each unique item number

the returned dataset should look like

```
    orderfileid item number item cost   warehouse
    2           1234        1.67             DFW
    3           2345        2.45             NYY
    3           6789        2.4              ORD
```

I think i tried every combination of select max(orderfileid) i can think of

Any help would be appriciated.
thanks

Comment: something among the lines of: `select distinct item_number, orderfileid, item_cost, warehouse from orders order by item_number, orderfileid desc` perhaps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to find your MAX values in a subquery, then use those results to join to your main table to retrieve the columns.

```
SELECT t.OrderFileId, t.ItemNumber, t.ItemCost, t.Warehouse
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT ItemNumber, MAX(OrderFileId) AS MaxOrderId
                        FROM YourTable
                        GROUP BY ItemNumber) q
            ON t.ItemNumber = q.ItemNumber
                AND t.OrderFileId = q.MaxOrderId
```

Comment: Thank you.   In trying this solution i am getting different results.   Perhaps I'm typing something wrong but I get only the value with a unique entry   I get the results for the item number 6789 and not the others.   Of course Im not using this simplified data set i have in the example, so I may be losing it in translation

Comment: @larry: I've confirmed that the query I've written returns the expected results for the sample data set you provided.

Comment: Thanks   I'll continue tweaking and let you  know results.  Thanks for getting me to next step.

Comment: It now works.  My example was too simple, I had a where filldate clause after your statement above and once I also included it in the select from the inner join everything works perfect.  Great Help!!1

Answer (score 4):

```
select 
    t.* 
from 
    table t 
    inner join (
        select itemnumber, max(orderfileid) maxof
        from table
        group by itemnumber
    ) m on t.itemnumber = m.itemnumber 
            and t.orderfileid = m.maxof
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even use Max. Just combine GROUP BY and ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM orders GROUP BY item_number ORDER BY orderfileid DESC
```

then for minimum just change to ASC

Comment: No because OP only wants 1 of each item, not all instances of the item ordered by the orderfield.

NOTE: I am justifying the Necro, because the answer is a Necro

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE orderfileid=(select max(orderfileid) from TABLE)
```

Comment: No. You're selecting `max(orderfileid)` for the entire table, not on a per ItemNumber basis.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to a similar problem on how to group things using partitioning and picking one per partition in mysql

[Deleting Rows: No Single Member Has More Than x Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824729/deleting-rows-no-single-member-has-more-than-x-records/6824909#6824909)

this is something similar to doing rank over in Oracle. my previous post was for oracle. my bad..

Comment: MySQL does not have window functions.

Answer (score -2):

I think what you are looking for is the "Having" clause. Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

select orderfileid, max(itemnumber), itemcost, warehouse from MyTable group by orderfileid having max(itemnumber) ;

Comment: Having is a post-process evaluation and will almost always be sub-optimal.