# Getting the MAX Record for the Most Recent Serial Numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table with some sample data.

```
Record_ID    Counter    Serial    Owner
1           0           AAA       Jack
2           1           AAA       Kevin
3           0           BBB       Jane
4           1           BBB       Wendy
```

Based on data similar to the above, I am trying to write a SQL query for MySQL that gets the record with the maximum `Counter` value per `Serial` number.  **The part I seem to be having trouble with is getting the query to get the last 50 unique serial numbers that were updated.**

Below is the query I came up with so far based on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860746/sql-selecting-multiple-columns-based-on-max-value-in-one-column).

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `history` his 
   INNER JOIN(SELECT serial, 
                     Max(counter) AS MaxCount 
              FROM   `tracking` 
              WHERE  serial IN (SELECT serial 
                                FROM   `history`) 
              GROUP  BY serial
              ORDER  BY record_id DESC) q 
           ON his.serial = q.serial 
              AND his.counter = q.maxcount 
LIMIT  0, 50
```

Comment: Where is the point of the Where clause in your subquery?

Comment: I meant to remove it initially, but the `WHERE serial IN (SELECT serial FROM \`history\`` was where I was trying to create another subquery to select the last 50 unique serial numbers that were updated.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL support the Top 50 command?

Comment: In MySQL, the equivalent of the `TOP` Clause is `LIMIT`.  Within the subquery you asked about in the above comment, I tried LIMIT 0, 50, but `LIMIT` can't be used in subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a classic [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem, which can be solved by something like this:

```
select his.Record_ID, his.Counter, his.Serial, his.Owner
from History his
inner join(
    select Serial, max(Counter) Counter
    from History
    group by Serial
) ss on his.Serial = ss.Serial and his.Counter = ss.Counter
```

If you are to have specific filters on your data set, you should apply the said filters in the sub-query.

Another source with more explanation on the problem here: [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/7745635#7745635)

Comment: Does this solution solve the problem of returning  just 50 entries with the last updated Serials?..

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro Thanks for your answer.  However, it doesn't seem to return the last 50 unique serials that were updated.