# How to get the data from max of two fields

Tags: sql, jpa, spring-data, ibm-cloud, criteria

The question here is similar:

[SQL Selecting multiple columns based on max value in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860746/sql-selecting-multiple-columns-based-on-max-value-in-one-column)

but in that question, it suggests sql. I want to do in java side.

In java spring boot, i wrote this:

```
 Qmk104 findFirstBypakAndpolOrderBytecDesczeyDesc(String pak, int pol)
```

so with that, i can return the row with max tec which has max zey also.

After that, i will get tec and zey:

```
int maxtec;
int maxzey;
```

and with those, i will make a query again to get the data with max tec which has max zey.

```
tec zey  pak 
0   1     24
1   2    24
2   0    25
2   1    25
4   5    26
5   0    27
5   1    28
5   2     2(this is max tec with zey. max tec= 5. tec 5 has max 1 zey)
5   2     4(but i need also this because max tec with zey so i will make another query to get  both)
```

in sql, i can get easy

```
select * from qmk104 f where POL=390097 and PAK='K'and
        (TEC) in
        (select max(t.TEC) from qmk104 t
         where t.POL=f.POL and t.PAK=f.PAK)
                                and ZEY in (
        select max(t.ZEY) from qmk104 t
        where t.POL=f.POL and t.PAK=f.PAK and t.TEC = f.TEC
    );
```

how can get it in spring data? With criteria?

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of the Criteria API is basically non-existent, but I can offer the following query which uses exists logic rather than `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM qmk104 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM qmk104 t2
                  WHERE t2.tec > t1.tec OR
                        t2.tec = t1.tec AND t2.zey > t1.zey);
```

### Demo

You might need a native query to make the above work, as JPQL does not seem to directly supports `EXISTS`.  While we're discussing native queries, another good way to approach this would be to use `RANK`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tec DESC, zey DESC) rnk
    FROM qmk104
) t
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

But again, you would need a native query here, or you could place the above code into a stored procedure and then call it from Java.

Comment: it is ibm sql. ',' gives error: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=se-sql0104-token-1-was-not-valid-valid-tokens-2